# finding consecutive numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server

ok - so i searched the internet for this, and none of the examples i found are exactly like mine.

i have a table with 5 columns and thousands of rows.
i need to find consecutive numbers within each row. i need to end up with 3 queries for the situations shown below

```
n1   n2   n3   n4   n5
=======================
 1     3    4    6    9   = should result in 1 (when checking for pairs)
 1     3    4    5    9   = should result in 1 (when checking for triplets)
 1     2    5    8    9   = should result in 1 (when checking for double pairs)
```

This is what i have to move the columns into rows, but i am not sure how to check this now.

```
select n1 from (
select n1 from myTable where Id  = 1
union all select n2 from myTable where Id = 1
union all select n3 from myTable where Id = 1
union all select n4 from myTable where Id = 1
union all select n5 from myTable where Id = 1
) t
order by n1
```

Thank you for all your help!

@TimBiegeleise, update :
so i found this on google for Gaps & Islands:

```
SELECT ID, StartSeqNo=MIN(SeqNo), EndSeqNo=MAX(SeqNo)
FROM (
SELECT ID, SeqNo
    ,rn=SeqNo-ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY SeqNo)
FROM dbo.GapsIslands) a
GROUP BY ID, rn;
```

this is my updated query converting the columns to rows (but it requires 2 statements, i much rather have 1) and implementing the island part - but i don't understand how that give me the result what i need (see above). below i show the original row data and the result.

```
select n1, IDENTITY (INT, 1, 1) AS ID 
into #test
from (
select n1 from myTable where Id  = 8
union all select n2 from myTable where Id = 8
union all select n3 from myTable where Id = 8
union all select n4 from myTable where Id = 8
union all select n5 from myTable where Id = 8
) as t
order by n1

SELECT ID, StartSeqNo=MIN(n1), EndSeqNo=MAX(n1)
FROM (
SELECT ID, n1
    ,rn=n1-ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY n1)
FROM #test) a
GROUP BY ID, rn

drop table #test

original row - should return 1 (when checking for "pair"/consecutive numbers
n1   n2   n3   n4   n5
=======================
31   27   28   36   12
```

the result i get with the above query:

```
    StartSeqNo  EndSeqNo
1   12          12
2   27          27
3   28          28
4   31          31
5   36          36
```

help :-) !

Comment: In the general case, this looks like a gaps and islands problem, except your data format renders the database fairly useless in helping.  You should definitely get your data for each sequence stored in a column, not across columns in a row.

Comment: thanks for your reply. that is what i thought as well, which is what the query is posted will do. It will create for each row a new temp table with 1 column. the result is one column with the number in different rows.

Comment: Can you tell us what database you are using? There are variations in the SQL between platforms that give different capabilities that may help in this situation.

Comment: sorry for the delay. i am using SQL server (i think its 2010) but considering moving this DB later to SQL Express

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, readin up on gaps and islands and it seams this could work. but how would i apply/code  it in this case?

Comment: @Gunnar Get the data into a single column and then use a second column for the n number.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, don't think i understand. the select i posted above does convert the column into rows - so i got that. but what do you mean with for the n number.   (not sure how to add the updated query, but i added an identity column to it)

Comment: Oh yeah I see that now.  You should run the analysis on `t` then.

Answer (score 0):

ok, i got it. this query returns a value of 1 for the above stated row

```
select COUNT(*) as pairs 
from (
SELECT StartSeqNo=MIN(n1), EndSeqNo=MAX(n1)
    FROM (
        SELECT n1, rn=n1-ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY n1)
            from (
                select n1 from myTable where Id  = 8
                union all select n2 from myTable where Id = 8
                union all select n3 from myTable where Id = 8
                union all select n4 from myTable where Id = 8
                union all select n5 from myTable where Id = 8
            ) t
    ) x
GROUP BY rn
) z
where StartSeqNo+1 = EndSeqNo
```

Comment: hmm, so this works great for 1 record (in this case row with ID 8). But how do I change this query to return 1 result for each row?

Comment: Anyone any ideas?